# SqlDataSource checkbox before code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

I'm populating an ASP.NET checkbox from a `SqlDataSource` added on the `.aspx` page, and then I need to access it in code behind, but I'm running into an issue in which my method is happening before the checkbox is populated and so it is giving me an item count of zero.

How do I make sure the checkbox is populated by the `SqlDataSource` before I access it with code?

Answer (score 0):

If the text label for the checkbox is getting populated, then a simple fix would be to put

```
if(!(chkBox.Text == "" || chkBox.Text == null))
{
     // Your function call, or actual function code.
}
```

before the offending code is run in your code behind. This code prevents the if statement from being true if the label isn't populated yet.

Comment: Since I'm getting my data from a SQLDataSource control on the ASPX page I don't have an option which I can find for when it loads.

Comment: So you want to call something when data is bound to the checkbox? What about using the **OnDataBinding** event?  You'd put it in the checkbox control tag was `OnDataBinding="myFunction"`  The function should only be called after data has been bound to the control.